# C# Convert FileStream.WriteLine to go to a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, stream, biztalk, biztalk-pipelines

I wrote some code in a console program and tested with files. 
Now I want to port it to a BizTalk Pipeline Component that implements a specific interface.  I wasn't aware that that `.Write` and `.WriteLine` methods from a File to a Memory Stream were so different.  I thought I would just be able to swap my objects. There is no `.WriteLine` method, and the .Write method requires offset and bytes (additional parameters).

So now, what is the best way to change my tested code to write to the memory stream, given that I have a lot of .WriteLine statements.  I could write to a StringBuffer first, but then I think that would blow the concept of streaming (i.e. would have the whole document in memory at one time).

```
// This is how I used the streams in the Console program 
//FileStream originalStream = File.Open(inFilename, FileMode.Open);
//StreamWriter streamToReturn = new StreamWriter(outFilename);

// This is how to get the input stream in the BizTalk Pipeline Componenet 
System.IO.Stream originalStream = pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();

MemoryStream streamToReturn = new MemoryStream();
streamToReturn.WriteLine("<" + schemaStructure.rootElement + ">");
```

There's a lot more code not shown here. Above is just to set the stage for what I did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.113).aspx) which you can use to call WriteLine.

```
MemoryStream streamToReturn = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(streamToReturn);
writer.WriteLine("<" + schemaStructure.rootElement + ">");
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems obvious now since I was using StreamWriter before! I called my variable a stream, when in fact it was a StreamWriter.

Comment: I also had to the .Flush on the StreamWriter, not the Stream.  Otherwise it ran, but the stream BizTalk emitted had some missing characters at the end.

Comment: @NealWalters - Correct as the `StreamWriter` needs to be flushed to the underlying `Stream` it is writing to.